# OSGI services strange behaviour

Tags: java, service, osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

I'm experiencing what I believe it's an strange behaviour from Osgi services and their tracking.

I've got two bundles: `Provider` and `Client`. Provider offers the "*comm service*" which Client receives and uses.

At the beginning, Client retrieved the service via the OSGi **TrackerService** thanks to this method on the `ClientActivator` class:

```
private CommService retrieveCommService(BundleContext bc) 
                              throws InterruptedException {

        //create the tracker
        ServiceTracker tracker = new ServiceTracker(bc, CommService.class.
                                                   getName(), null);
        tracker.open();

        //timeout of 5 seconds to find the service
        CommService service = (CommService) tracker.waitForService(5000);
        tracker.close();

        return service;
    }
```

This way, the tracker found the service when the activator of the `Client` bundle was executed.

If the ServiceTracker works properly, this is what I see when I type *services* on the OSGi console:

```
{some.project.folder.imaComms.CommService}={service.id=46}
  Registered by bundle: MA_Provider [2062]
  Bundles using service:
    MA_Client [2565]
```

---

Anyway, after reading several documentation about OSGi services, I decided to use **DS** instead of ServiceTrackers.

So, I created the components (provider and client xml files) and implemented the bind and unbind methods:

```
 public void setComms(CommService comm){        
        this.comm = comm;
        System.out.println("got comms!");
    }

    public void unsetComms(CommService comm){           
        this.comm=null;
        System.out.println("lost comms..");
    }
```

And, this time, this is what I see when I type *services* on the Console:

```
{some.project.folder.imaComms.CommService}={component.name=
 MA_Comm_Provider, component.id=18, service.id=47}
  Registered by bundle: MA_Provider [2062]
  Bundles using service:
        MA_Client [2565]
```

So, whenever I stopped the `Provider` bundle, the message *lost comms...* appeared on console. When I started it again, *got comms*! was the message.

---

Everything perfect so far. But I wanted to make a last test. I implemented the bind and unbind methods, the component definition, but I also let the **ServiceTracker** find the service on the **ClientActivator**.

The result is somehow strange.

When I start the OSGi framework, *got comms!* appears on console, as if the **DS** bind method was working and offering the service to my `Client`. But if I type *services*, this is what I got:

```
 {some.project.folder.imaComms.CommService}={service.id=46}
      Registered by bundle: MA_Provider [2062]
      Bundles using service:
        MA_Client [2565]


 {some.project.folder.imaComms.CommService}={component.name=
  MA_Comm_Provider, component.id=18, service.id=47}
      Registered by bundle: MA_Provider [2062]
      No Bundles using this service.
```

The Client is using the service via ServiceTracker. If I stop the ProviderService, I got this message from the unbind method: **lost comms*...*

What happens if I start the bundle again? Yeah, "*got comms*!" appears on console...but then again, if I take a look at services, the **service id 47** (DS service) is not being used by anyone. *What?* O_o

Any clue of what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Also, forgot to mention: Whenever I restart the `Provider` bundle, Osgi takes about 2-3 minutes starting the bundle, and it completely stops any other bundles' work.

---

UPDATE 28/03/14

*XML files for provider and client DS*

**Provider**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0"  name="MA_Comms_Provider">
       <implementation class="some.project.folder.maComms.CommServiceImpl"/>
       <service>
          <provide interface="some.project.folder.imaComms.CommService"/>
       </service>
    </scr:component>
```

**Client**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="MA_Comms_consumer">
   <implementation class="some.project.folder.maClient.MyClientImpl"/>
   <reference bind="setComms" cardinality="1..1" interface="some.project.folder.imaComms.CommService" name="CommService" policy="static" unbind="unsetComms"/>
</scr:component>
```

*Manifest files for Provider and Client*

**Provider**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MA_Provider
Bundle-SymbolicName: MA_Provider
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: src/,
 .
Bundle-Activator: myActivator
Export-Package: ...
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: ...,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.5.0",
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.2"
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/CommsProvider.xml
```

**Client**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MaClient
Bundle-SymbolicName: MA_Client
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: src/,
 .
Bundle-Activator: ...
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: ...,
 org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.4.2"
Export-Package: es.techabout.meetabout.macomms
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/CommsConsumer.xml, ...
```

It should be noted that I omitted the real names of folders, classes and services, so even if my text has any error regarding names of classes, folders ..., I assure you that the real project is build with no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Which Osgi implementation are you using ?

Comment: Equinox. Forgot to tell that, sorry

Comment: Do you have both a DS declaration of the comms service *and* a service registration in the Provider bundle activator? That would cause the same service to be registered twice.

Comment: Yes, I have it: "But I wanted to make a last test. I implemented the bind and unbind methods, the component definition, but I also let the ServiceTracker find the service on the ClientActivator". The issue is, it's being registered twice, and the bind and unbind methods are working...even thou, no one seems to be using the DS service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you have installed the following bundles:

1. Provider using DS
2. Provider registering service directly
3. Client using DS
4. Client using ServiceTracker

If you start all those bundles, you see the DS Client found one of the Provider services. You also see that if you stop the bundle that provides that service, the DS Client does *not* find the other Provider service. That might sound odd, but could be explained if you have managed to partition your class space. For a definitive answer about that, we'd need all 4 bundle's manifests, but my guess is that the DS Client is wired to the export of one of the providers and that the other provider has a different export.

The fact that you don't see the Client using ServiceTracker show up can be explained because you open and close that tracker in your code. After closing it, OSGi no longer regards the service as "in use". Yes you still keep a reference around, but you don't know if the service is still there.

So let us see the manifests (and maybe also the DS XML) so we can see if my theory is correct.

Comment: Mm more or less, but I only have two bundles: Provider and Client. Provider registers the service directly (with ServiceTracker) and at the same time has a manifest that registers the service via DS. The client uses both ServiceTracker and DS as well. Hope it helps to make things more clear, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok, so one provider registers two services, and when it is stopped, both go away again. That also explains why the client finds only one service, and when both services go away, it has none again. Still, providing the actual XML and bundle manifests as part of the question would help (as I stated before, I'm "guessing" a bit now, because there's things we don't know).

Comment: First of all Marcel, thanks for your time. I want to make clear that this is a "why-does-this-act-this-way" question, not a real issue I'm struggling with (since the code does work perfectly). I added the XML files and Manifests for the two bundles. Again, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem. Your DS version appeared to be working fine, so you decide to mess with it and then it doesn't work any more? Perhaps go back to what was working.

service.id=46 seems to be a "raw" service registration by your provider bundle. service.id=47 is a registration by DS on behalf of your provider bundles. See the component.name service property. So you have the provider bundle registering 2 services.

You don't show the component description for your client bundles, so we can assume it would be fine with either service, so one of the two is picked.

Finally, you original use of ServiceTracker is wrong. The tracker must remain open while you use the service. When you use a tracker, you never hold the service object directly in a long term variable. You hold the tracker in a long term variable and consult it for the service object each time you need the service. Otherwise, you are assuming that once you get the service object that it is valid forever.

Comment: It works fine. I didn't mess anything, I was just making some tests. I know what service 46 and 47 do, as I explain in the question. You should read it again if you think my main problem are the osgi services not working anymore.My issue is not "it's not working", but "why does it work that way": Seems like the service 47 is never being used, but the bind and unbind methods of the DS services I declared (they are declared fine and work properly if no service is registered in the tracker) are in fact working, as they use and throw away services.

Comment: Your client bundle can use either service (46 or 47). The client does not care who registered the service. Only that the service matches the selection criteria.

Also the tracker does not register services. It is about using services.